# What do I use to send SMS messages from an application server?

Tags: java, sms

Sorry if this is an obvious question, but some preliminary googling came up with nothing.

I'm working with a Java EE server that links to some business servers and I'm looking into an SMS messaging service to notify users of important information. Is there some sort of service with an API that offers this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Disclaimer, I do developer evangelism part time at Nexmo.*

There are a few SMS APIs out that I've used:

- [Nexmo](http://nexmo.com)
- [Twilio](http://twilio.com)
- [Tropo](http://tropo.com)

If you're sending internationally, I think your best would be Nexmo. Or if you're accepting any incoming messages, Nexmo's pricing model will help you there. All three APIs are straight forward REST/HTTP APIs.

Here's a [Java API Client for Nexmo](https://github.com/Nexmo/nexmo-java-sdk).

Answer (score 0):

aside from the SMS APIs mentioned by the user above (see Tim Lytle's answer), another company that has developed an API for notifying users of important information (time sensitive, security-encrypted, etc.) is [Message Whiz - Sms messaging service](https://messagewhiz.com/sms-messaging-service/).

their rates are competitive and they offer a pay-by-results payment model.

good luck.